# How to replicate a figure describing standard error of the mean in R?

Tags: r, plot, standard-error

The first figure in [link](http://www.biostathandbook.com/standarderror.html) here shows a very nice example of how to visualise standard error and I would like to replicate that in R.

I'm getting there with the following

```
set.seed(1)
pop<-rnorm(1000,175,10)
mean(pop)
hist(pop)
#-------------------------------------------
# Plotting Standard Error for small Samples 
#-------------------------------------------
smallSample <- replicate(10,sample(pop,3,replace=TRUE)) ; smallSample
smallMeans<-colMeans(smallSample)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
x<-c(1:10)
plot(x,smallMeans,ylab="",xlab = "",pch=16,ylim = c(150,200))
abline(h=mean(pop))
#-------------------------------------------
# Plotting Standard Error for Large Samples 
#-------------------------------------------
largeSample <- replicate(10,sample(pop,20,replace=TRUE)) 
largeMeans<-colMeans(largeSample)
x<-c(1:10)
plot(x,largeMeans,ylab="",xlab = "",pch=16,ylim = c(150,200))
abline(h=mean(pop))
```

But I'm not sure how to plot the raw data as they have with the X symbols. Thanks.

Comment: Try `ggplot2` package. A basic one would be `ggplot(data.frame(x, smallMeans), aes(x=x, y = smallMeans))+geom_point()+geom_line()+geom_hline(yintercept = mean(pop))`

Comment: Thanks for your response. That gets close to what I've done so far (see the updated code) but I'd like to be able to overlay the raw data points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base plotting, you need to use the `arrows` function. 
In R there is no function (ASAIK) that computes standard error so try this

```
sem <- function(x){
     sd(x) / sqrt(length(x))
}
```

Plot (using pch = 4 for the x symbols)

```
plot(x, largeMeans, ylab = "", xlab = "", pch = 4, ylim = c(150,200))
abline(h = mean(pop))
arrows(x0 = 1:10, x1 = 1:10, y0 = largeMeans - sem(largeSample) * 5, largeMeans + sem(largeSample) * 5, code = 0)
```

Note: the SE's from the data you provided were quite small, so i multiplied them by 5 to make them more obvious

**Edit**

Ahh, to plot all the points, then perhaps `?matplot`, and `?matpoints` would be helpful? Something like:

```
matplot(t(largeSample), ylab = "", xlab = "", pch = 4, cex = 0.6, col = 1)
abline(h = mean(pop))
points(largeMeans, pch = 19, col = 2)
```

Is this more the effect you're after?

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty close to what I'm after but I'd rather plot the raw data points rather than standard error bars.